# Installing a 240V 30 A outlet for EV charging

Tags: electrical-panel

I would like to install a 240V 30A outlet for EV charging in my deeded parking space in the common basement garage in my condominium building.  The electrical closet with all individual unit electric meters is conveniently adjacent to my deeded parking space.  Rather than drill a hole through a steel reinforced concrete floor from my unit into the garage to run a wire from my in-unit main breaker panel to the EV charging station, can I do the following:  1.  install a new main breaker panel between the unit electric meter (in the electrical closet) and the in-unit breaker panel (thus making the in-unit breaker panel a subpanel); and 2. run a wire from the new main breaker panel (which would be physically located in the electrical closet in which the unit electric meter is located) to supply my 240V 30A EV charging station?  The condominium is located in Cambridge, MA.

Comment: What size are the feeder wires going up to your unit panel from the main breaker?

Comment: I am not sure...I will need to contact the association.

Answer (score 1):

First you have to consult with your Condo HOA to see what their restrictions are and then proceed per their instructions. Otherwise your thinking about putting the mains by the meter and sub feeding your home panel and new charger is the least expensive and least intrusive of your options.

Comment: Thank you!  Yes, I will need to consult the HOA, but our very own president chose the other option of drilling through reinforced concrete, so I suspect this solution will be more acceptable.  The new mains by the meter would not need to be very large, as it would have just two breakers, correct?

Comment: @SeaDoctor - I don't know what you mean by large, but it would have to have enough space to install both mains. The most space saving and common method would be to use a small panel rated to accept the amperage of both breakers.

Comment: I mean large in physical size, as you have correctly assumed.  Clearly, it must be able to accommodate the amperage of both breakers regardless of physical size.  Thank you for your help.